# NER Incremental training with Spacy

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I would like to **incrementally train a NER Spacy Model**.

By incrementally I mean send a first batch of N training samples, get a first model, then send a second batch of M training samples and get a model identical as if the N+M samples would have been sent in one batch and the model trained.

To be clear, this is not about adding samples after the model has been fully trained. Instead it is the ability to save intermediate states in the model so we can "resume" and add more training samples.

This is very useful if the number of samples is large or to create an "active learning" systems.

It seems doable with NLTK according to [this article](http://www.stokastik.in/building-an-incremental-named-entity-recognizer-system/) :  and I was wondering if this can be done with Spacy.

So far I have trained my own custom NER model with Spacy using nlp.update but it does not seem to store any intermediate state that supports incremental training.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible in spaCy. Your approach with `nlp.update` is correct; once you have added your second batch of training samples, you just need to make a call to `nlp.to_disk("/path")` (https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading). Then you can continue this process by loading your saved model again.